# clipPath with d3.js and angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a graph built with d3.js embedded in my AngularJS project and I have a problem keeping my lines inside the chart area when I zoom in (using d3.behavior.zoom).
I don't have the base tag in my header. The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
   this.svg = d3.select(elem).append("svg")
      .attr('class', 'plot')
      .attr('width', this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
      .attr('height', this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .call(responsivefy);

   this.svg.append('defs').append('svg:clipPath')
      .attr('id', 'clip')
   .append('svg:rect')
     .attr('width', this.width)
     .attr('height', this.height)
     .attr('x', this.margin.left)
     .attr('y', this.margin.top);

   this.svg = this.svg.append('g')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

   this.curves_layer = this.svg.append('g');
   var paths = this.curves_layer.selectAll('.line').data(data.series);
   paths.transition()
     .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); }).attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
     .attr('stroke', function(d) { return that.color(d.name)});
   paths.enter().append('path').attr('class', 'line')
     .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); }).attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
     .attr('stroke', function(d) { return that.color(d.name)});
   paths.exit().remove();
```

I tried to apply the clip-path attribute to this.curves_layer group, I tried to put an absolute url instead of just #clip. Nothing works. When I zoom in, the paths overflow the chart area.

The related angular directive looks like this:

```
   plots.directive('plot', ['$timeout', '$compile',
   function($timeout, $compile) {
      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope: {
            chart: '=',
            data : '='
         },
         link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('chart', function(newVal, oldVal) {
               if (!newVal) return;

               // Clear the directive
               elem.children().remove()
               scope.plot = null;
            });

            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
               if (!newVal) return;
               if (!scope.plot) {
                  scope.plot = new Plot(scope.data, elem[0]);
               } else {
                  scope.plot.update(scope.data);
               }

               $compile(elem)(scope);

            }, true);
         }
      };
   }]);
```

Comment: D3.js with jQuery is generally less problematic and simpler than putting D3.js into AngularJS when D3 updates are involved.  In order for someone to help troubleshoot you will need to provide your angular code that interacts with D3.  If you simply put a D3 DOM elements within an Angular ng-app context, then updates no longer work.  [How to updateable D3 in Angular](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html)

Comment: I added the angular directive code. But the update does work fine. When I zoom, it zooms. The problem really is that the curves that I am plotting, or the bars in the bar charts overflow the chart area. For example, I will have bars on the left side of the y-axis. And having a clippath to avoid this seems to have absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem by using `svg` tags, dropping the `clipPath` approach. Instead of:

```
this.curves_layer = this.svg.append('g');
```

I used:

```
this.curves_layer = this.svg.append('svg')
   .attr('height', this.height)
   .attr('width', this.width);
```

I didn't know it was possible to have multiple `svg` tags nested. Apparently it is and everything outside a given svg is clipped.